# A many-to-one assignment problem with profits depending on the assignment

Tags: algorithm, many-to-one

Sorry for asking a similar question in a short time. This problem is similar to [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67885859/is-a-many-to-one-assignment-problem-np-hard), but with slight differene.

It's still a many-to-one matching problem with *M* tasks and *N* people. Each task can only be assigned to one person and one person can get more than one task. However, there is three different profits when assigning a task, one for the task itself, one for the person who get the task, and one for the overall benefit. All three profits can be either positive or negative. A task can be assigned to a person only if the **sum profits** of both task and person is positive. In addition, the profit of task and person depends on the combination of tasks assigned to a person. The goal is to maximize the sum of overall profits.

For example, if task *i* is assigned to person *j*, we denote *G*={*i*, *j*}. Then, the task gets P<sub>G->i</sub>, the person receives P<sub>G->j</sub>, and the overall benefit is P<sub>G</sub>=P<sub>G->j</sub>+P<sub>G->i</sub>. If this case, P<sub>G->j</sub>, P<sub>G->i</sub>, and P<sub>G</sub> must be positive. Otherwise, the assignment should be failed.

Another example: If we have two tasks *i*, *i+1*, and one person *j*, we can have the possible assignments: *G<sub>1</sub>*={*i*, *j*}, *G<sub>2</sub>*={*i+1*, *j*} and *G<sub>3</sub>*={*i*, *i+1*, *j*}. Suppose P<sub>G<sub>1</sub>->j</sub>, P<sub>G<sub>1</sub>->i</sub>, P<sub>G<sub>1</sub></sub>, P<sub>G<sub>2</sub>->i+1</sub>, and P<sub>G<sub>2</sub></sub> is positive, while P<sub>G<sub>2</sub>->j</sub> is negative, then the following assignments are available:

1. Assign only task *i* to person *j*.
2. Assign both task *i* and *i+1* to person *j* if P<sub>G<sub>3</sub>->j</sub> > 0, and P<sub>G<sub>3</sub></sub> > P<sub>G<sub>1</sub></sub>. Note that P<sub>G<sub>3</sub>->j</sub> is not equal to P<sub>G<sub>2</sub>->j</sub>+P<sub>G<sub>1</sub>->j</sub> and P<sub>G<sub>3</sub></sub> is not equal to P<sub>G<sub>1</sub></sub> + P<sub>G<sub>2</sub></sub>.

Note: Assigning task *i+1* to person *j* is impossible since P<sub>G<sub>2</sub>->j</sub> < 0.

**"P<sub>G<sub>3</sub></sub> is not equal to P<sub>G<sub>1</sub></sub> + P<sub>G<sub>2</sub></sub>"** indicates that we need to re-calculate the profits every time we try to assign an addition task to a person (Different from the problem in my previous post). We can, still, obtain a sub-optimal solution through a greedy algorithm. However, I am wondering if this is an NP-hard problem because it seems that the only way to get an optimal solution is the full search on all combinations, which, indicates very high computation overhead.

Is there any polynomial-time algorithm that can solve this problem except for the full search on all combinations?

Comment: If we only have oracle access to P, then no – we can bury a very profitable subset somewhere and make the algorithm go look for it, resulting in an exponential lower bound. Does P have any useful structure?

Comment: Thank you for commenting! Unfortunately, P does not have any useful structure. In fact, we get P for every possible G by solving a convex problem with CVX. So to get a very profitable subset of the tasks for every person still requires a full search on all combinations of tasks.

Comment: I'd formulate the assignment problem as an integer program then and see what happens.

Comment: So a useful structure of P is needed in order to apply a polynomial-time algorithm to solve this problem optimally. If there is no useful structure, then we can only obtain a sub-optimal solution in polynomial time. Am I correct?

Comment: Most likely under standard complexity theoretic assumptions, but I can't be sure without the details of what you're doing in CVX.

Comment: Thanks! About the CVX, since it is difficult to post the details here, I can only provide general descriptions, though is may not be helpful: P is solved by an SCA algorithm which is solved by CVX iteratively. There are two multi-dimensional variables, multiple linear constraints, and one logarithmic constraint. The objective is the sum of products of the two variables.

Comment: Yeah, I would be pretty confident of finding a suitable gadget.